# HP Wireless mouse stopped working on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-mouse

I've been using a HP wireless optical mobile mouse (WX407AA) on my MacBook Pro for the past couple of weeks. It suddenly stopped working this morning. I've tried it on a PC (Windows 7) and it's working fine. I can also use another mouse (a Microsoft USB mouse) on the MacBook without any issues.

I've replaced the batteries just to make sure and also plugged it into a different USB port on the Mac, but still no luck.

Unfortunately I'm pretty new to Mac so I'm not really sure were to start looking. Any help appreciated!

UPDATE: And now it started working again. Any ideas of how I can pinpoint the cause for the issue?

Comment: i'm sure this was [cross-posted](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16975/hp-wireless-mouse-stopped-working-on-mac) from [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com)

Comment: Yes, sorry I've deleted the other post

Comment: you don't actually need to delete it - i'm just posting it in case someone else wants to answer it there